# how to solve nonlinear partial differential equation of fractional order

Tags: differential-equations

[image: question 4.1]

How to solve this equation by using homotopy perturbation method with the help of the riemann liouville integral?

Based on homotopy technique, this is as far as I can go. Somebody please help me

(∂u_0)/∂t= x + xt^2,                                             u_0(x,0)=0,
(∂u_1)/∂t= (∂u_0)/∂t - u_0(u_0)*x - D*(*t)^α u_0,                u_1 (x,0)=0,
(∂u_2)/∂t= (∂u_1)/∂t - u_0(u_1)_x - u_1(u_0)*x - D*(*t)^α u_1,   u_2(x,0)=0,

How can I use mathematica to integrate the above system?

Comment: Unfortunately, fractional-order DEs are not yet supported by *Mathematica*. You may have to roll your own numerical method.

Comment: @J.M. could you show me how to write the coding of the above edited question please?

Comment: This link has a notebook that does something similar: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FractionalDerivative.html

Comment: Its a very nice question: it shows a way into a new field. A pity that such questions are being blocked by the community.